# MySQL conditional database structure change

Tags: mysql, versioning

The problem is: I would like to create a conditional `CREATE/ALTER` scripts (the condition would be an integer value of database version). How to do it? Seems that MySQL IF won't help. Neither `ALTER` nor `CREATE/DROP` table seem to work under some specific condition.

Background: I want to provide versions with my database, so I created a simple version table, where I hold a number. As the project will carry on, the structure will evolve and each alter table/create table/etc. will create new version (along with a MySQL modification script). I'm having few environments with exact copies of the database and I want to make it the database upgrade itself automatically without any outside script (PHP/Python/etc.).

Comment: [Get Your Database Under Version Control](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/02/get-your-database-under-version-control.html).

Comment: this problem is somehow resolved in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931888/mysql-stored-procedure-set-value-from-table/13932436#13932436