# mysql stored procedure set value from table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've got a following, simple table:

```
mysql> select * from version;
+----+---------+
| id | version |
+----+---------+
|  1 | 1       |
+----+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need to create a stored procedure that will do something (or nothing) depending on the value of this table (precisely, the only row of this table).

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS upgrade_version $$
CREATE PROCEDURE upgrade_version(current_version INTEGER, script TEXT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE version INT(11);
  SET version = (SELECT `version` FROM `version` WHERE `id` = 1 LIMIT 1);
  SELECT version;
  IF version = current_version + 1 THEN
    PREPARE upgrade_stmt FROM script;
    EXECUTE upgrade_stmt;
    UPDATE `version` SET `version` = `version` + 1 WHERE `id` = 1;
  ENDIF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

To be called within:

```
CALL upgrade_version(1,'ALTER TABLE ...');
```

It is syntactically incorrect, mysql returns:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'script;
    EXECUTE upgrade_stmt;
    UPDATE `version` SET `version` = `version`' at line 7
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Do you get this message at procedure definition or when you try to call it ?

Comment: I get this error when defining the procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS upgrade_version $$
CREATE PROCEDURE upgrade_version(current_version INT, script TEXT)
BEGIN
  SELECT `version` into @ver FROM `version` WHERE `id` = 1 LIMIT 1;  
  SET @s = script;
  IF @ver = current_version + 1 THEN
    PREPARE upgrade_stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE upgrade_stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE upgrade_stmt;
    UPDATE `version` SET `version` = `version` + 1 WHERE `id` = 1;
  END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 5):

I dont understand why you are selecting that "SELECT version", If you want to select the data you have to retrieve it into a varialbe, that statement works fine when you use it directly at the terminal. And are you sure that you have prepared_stmt in your scripts..!? possible fix is :

1. change the varible name version to version_v
2. instead of this:

   SET version = (SELECT `version` FROM `version` WHERE `id` = 1 LIMIT 1);
   SELECT version;

try this:

```
SELECT `version` INTO Version_v FROM `version` WHERE `id` = 1 LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Set Value To Declare variable

```
       DELIMITER $$
       create procedure Testing()
           begin
            declare Regione int;   
            set Regione=(select  id from users
            where id=1) ;
            select Regione ;
           end $$
         DELIMITER;
```