# Error when creating a stored procedure when using XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

Please help me, what's wrong with my query? Why does my query work fine when using Navicat but not when using phpmyadmin from xampp?

I get this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

Please help me, you can check the query below

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_view_laporan`(
    IN `varPName` VARCHAR(255),
    IN `varThn` INT(11),
    IN `varBln` INT(11)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        status_pivot LONGTEXT; DECLARE kanwil VARCHAR(255); DECLARE sqlQuery LONGTEXT;
    SET
        status_pivot =(
        SELECT
            GROUP_CONCAT(
                DISTINCT CONCAT(
                    'SUM(IF(status_id =',
                    status_id,
                    ', jml,0)) as ',
                    LOWER(
                REPLACE
                    (nama_status, ' ', '_')
                )
                )
            )
        FROM
            (
            SELECT
                @thn := varThn thn,
                @bln := varBln bln
        ) parm,
        view_posisi_status
    ); IF varPName IS NULL OR varPName = 0 THEN
SET
    kanwil = 'WHERE 1 '; ELSE
SET
    kanwil = CONCAT(
        'WHERE parent_name LIKE "%',
        varPName,
        '%"'
    );
END IF;
SET
    sqlQuery = CONCAT(
        'SELECT IFNULL(posisi_id,"TOTAL") posisi_id, parent_name, nama_posisi,',
        status_pivot,
        ' FROM (select @thn:=',
        varThn,
        ' thn, @bln:=',
        varBln,
        ' bln) parm,
    view_posisi_status ',
        kanwil,
        '
    group by posisi_id WITH ROLLUP'
    );
PREPARE
    stmt
FROM
    sqlQuery;
EXECUTE
    stmt;
DEALLOCATE
PREPARE
    stmt;
END
```

I'm pretty sure there's nothing wrong with my code, but xampp says otherwise.

**UPDATE :**

Tried the suggestion given by FanoFN but still getting the same message
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/scvxtPrvbfcYzv3EepDyjw/1

**UPDATE 2:**

I tried to shorten the query, it works with Navicat, but not for xampp.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/scvxtPrvbfcYzv3EepDyjw/2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql stored procedure set value from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931888/mysql-stored-procedure-set-value-from-table)

Comment: Still can't go well. Please help me.

Comment: what is your exact MariaDB version? Run `SELECT version();` to check

Comment: my mariadb version is 10.4.6-MariaDB. I'm also confused, why is there an error in fiddle too. But don't worry, the query runs fine when using php artisan migrate from laravel even though an error occurs in xampp.

Comment: Sorry, wrong fiddle.. here's the correct one https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/scvxtPrvbfcYzv3EepDyjw/3